# React Redux debugging props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

I am new to react and i've been trying to practice ajax calls, and I cannot get my props function to work. I am able to get the json data from the facebook response, I just cannot pass it in to the action. For brevity I trimmed down the code.

**user-list.js**

```
class UserList extends Component {

    responseFacebook(response) {
      console.log(response);
      this.props.login(response)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <FacebookLogin
                  appId="mysecretappid10239"
                  autoLoad={true}
                  fields="name,email,picture"
                  scope="public_profile,user_friends,user_actions.books"
                  callback={this.responseFacebook}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        users: state.users.data,
        fetched: state.users.fetched
    };
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return bindActionCreators({login: login}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(UserList);
```

**actions file:**

I am trying to print the payload to see if it works.

```
export const login = (payload) => {
    console.log("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$" + payload)
};
```

**This is the error I get:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'login' of undefined
```

**Question:**

How do I go about this pattern correctly without having the error?

Answer (score 1):

Change `callback={this.responseFacebook}` to `callback={this.responseFacebook.bind(this)}`.

Or, better, bind it in `constructor`.

```
class UserList extends Component {
    constructor(){
    super();
    this.responseFacebook = this.responseFacebook.bind(this);
    }
    responseFacebook(response) {
      console.log(response);
      this.props.login(response)
    }
    ...
```